# Routing issues between areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a area 1, that has a redirect to area 2:

```
return View("~/areas/2/views/default/index.cshtml");
```

However, the view renders fine, but it is not getting its model from the controller nor triggers in debugger. Same result with `return redirecttoroute` etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add code where you specify the URL of action method which resides in Area Controller ?

Comment: That first code isn't a redirect, it's just rendering a view. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Returning a view from a different area just loads that view; it's not the same as a redirect.

Comment: I am trying to render a view (located in area2) with its model that is called from a actionmethod in area 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a model into the view, [pass it in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29):

```
  return View(viewName, model);
```

Comment: This might work, although it is a little bit odd becouse I have to pull out the model from area 2 and then render view. But then routing is a over complicated chapter aswell :P